# customize destination for user_login with modal_forms link?

Tags: users

I am using the [Login Destination](https://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module to form rules for login customization. But they seem to be failing when modal_form is opened for the user login.
Can any one suggest something ?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the following for ctools modal_form issues https://drupal.org/node/1329040 there is some code there that should allow you to set the redirect url using PHP to where you need it to go.

You should also double check that your modules are both up to date, there did not seem to be any open issues about computability between the two modules.